# Does this matrix identity hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

For invertible matrices A and B does the identity:

$$
(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1} = A - A(A+B)^{-1}A 
$$

hold? My supervisor suggested that they are equal but I haven't been able to prove this and in the matrix cookbook (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) there are separate identities for both sides of this equation, but they are not given as equal to each other.

Comment: Smells like [The Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

Comment: Don't we  first  need to assume that $A+B$ is invertible?

Comment: @ArpitKansal There is a $(A+B)^{-1}$ in the identity. Obviously you need to assume that $A+B$ is invertible...

Comment: Page 18, relation 157 of your linked pdf.

Comment: Ah yes of course, it's just the woodbury identity with U and V equal  to the identity matrix. Thanks a lot guys! :)

Comment: @Fabian It smells even more like [Hua's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hua%27s_identity), because it is just the second form listed at wikipedia with $a$ and $b$ exchanged with their respective inverses. I'm glad to learn of this more general thing, though..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
A-A(A+B)^{-1}A &=&A-(A+B-B)(A+B)^{-1}A \\
&=&B(A+B)^{-1}A=[A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1}]^{-1} \\
&=&(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Dear @Urgje You've nailed it.bravo!